# Android APK Release Notes

Tags: android, release, release-management

In other programs I've developed, I like to include release notes in the program, so that people can view the differences from program version to program version. I wish to do the same with some android apks I've been working on.

I'm curious if there is a built in feature I can use for this, or if I just need to use some standard widgets.

Comment: Google Play has fields for this. Adding it to the app itself might be redundant.

Comment: This is a private apk which is not controlled by google play.

Comment: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/changeloglib

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way of doing this.

My reccommendation would be to add a section to the `Help` screen (accessed from the overflow menu) that contained those release notes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Android Change Log in my apps. Check it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-change-log/)

It's easily customizable with HTML/CSS, easy to use, and works with Android SDK 1.5 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Another library you could use is [Inscription](http://martin.cubeactive.com/inscription/)